# using Try in flatMap

Tags: scala

Im writing my own class Success or Error. I want to create a way to build `SuccessOrError` from `Try` and then use `Try` instead of ugly `try-catch` in flatMap. But I'm stuck at this point. How should I best write a function fromTry in order to be able to write like this?
`case SuccessOrError.Success(v) ⇒ SuccessOrError.fromTry(Try(f(v)))`

```
  enum SuccessOrError[+V]:

    case Success(x: V) extends SuccessOrError[V]

    case Error(e : Throwable) extends SuccessOrError[V]

    def flatMap[Q](f: V ⇒ SuccessOrError[Q]): SuccessOrError[Q] =
      this match
        case SuccessOrError.Success(v)   ⇒ try f(v) catch case NonFatal(e) => SuccessOrError.Error(e) 
        case SuccessOrError.Error(e)  ⇒ SuccessOrError.Error(e)


object SuccessOrError:
   def fromTry[Q](f: Try[Q]): SuccessOrError[Q] = ???
```

Comment: I`m not sure about parameters in fromTry too

Comment: I on't get what your problem is, seems pretty obvious: `def fromTry[Q](t: Try[Q]) = t.fold(Error, Success)`. Also, if I may ask, _why_  are you reimplementing `Try`? You know you can just do `type SuccessOrError[A] = Try[A]` if you just don't like the name, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting from `Try` to another error model is quite a common practice. Perhaps consider how they approach it in scala-cats library as inspiration

[Validated](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/9753b344df3c75e71799ea666d2018ee5f19747f/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Validated.scala#L1107)

```
  /**
   * Converts a `Try[A]` to a `Validated[Throwable, A]`.
   */
  def fromTry[A](t: Try[A]): Validated[Throwable, A] =
    t match {
      case Failure(e) => invalid(e)
      case Success(v) => valid(v)
    }
```

or [Either](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/9753b344df3c75e71799ea666d2018ee5f19747f/core/src/main/scala/cats/syntax/either.scala#L378)

```
  /**
   * Converts a `Try[A]` to a `Either[Throwable, A]`.
   */
  def fromTry[A](t: Try[A]): Either[Throwable, A] =
    t match {
      case Failure(e) => left(e)
      case Success(v) => right(v)
    }
```

or [ApplicativeError](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/9753b344df3c75e71799ea666d2018ee5f19747f/core/src/main/scala/cats/ApplicativeError.scala#L227)

```
  /**
   * If the error type is Throwable, we can convert from a scala.util.Try
   */
  def fromTry[A](t: Try[A])(implicit ev: Throwable <:< E): F[A] =
    t match {
      case Success(a) => pure(a)
      case Failure(e) => raiseError(e)
    }
```

Note the pattern (bad pun, applogies) of simply pattern matching on happy and unhappy cases, so we can try emulating it

```
def fromTry[Q](f: Try[Q]): SuccessOrError[Q] = 
  f match {
    case scala.util.Failure(e) => SuccessOrError.Error(e)
    case scala.util.Success(v) => SuccessOrError.Success(v)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for great information! I have one more question: if we use a function  fromTry[Q](f: Try[Q]): SuccessOrError[Q], then how do we call SuccessOrError.fromTry(Try(f(v))) in the flatMap?

Comment: @ElenaVishnyakova Note how `SuccessOrError.fromTry(Try(f(v)))` returns `SuccessOrError[SuccessOrError[Q]]` where the value is wrapped twice, so although we avoided ugly try-catch, now we have to work a bit more to unwrap the inner value. We could pattern match yet again, so something like `SuccessOrError.fromTry(Try(f(v))) match { case Success(v) => v ...`